# Apache .htaccess redirect do not find match in url when script is in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an url like "http://www.example.com/mobiles/page.php?id=999". I want to redirect all requests on urls like this on to new ones like "http://www.example.com/mobiles/page/show/999".

I wrote .htaccess in mobiles subfolder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/show/%1? [R=301,L]
```

But the match does not fire. What the problem is? Thanks in advance!

**update:**

I'm having big difficulties to write htaccess regexp which matches "page.php?id=" in url like this "http://www.example.com/mobiles/page.php?id=999". I've checked the online htaccess testers but anything really helps...

Comment: Does the new url work if you type it directly in your browser address bar?

Comment: yes, it does! I explain a little bit more: i'm writing the site using yii2. I've enabled pretty urls. Route www.example.com/mobiles/page/show/898 works perfectly. But I want to redirect from an old url structure to a new one. Old url was: www.example.com/mobiles/page.php?id=898 . Now I update the question and post htaccess files i'm using at this moment. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight typo in your RewriteCond. You forgot to add your dir name to the pattern.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mobiles/page\.php\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I've spent 1,5 days trying to find the mistake cause I'm not strong in configuring apache and it's modules.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mobiles/page/show/([^/]*)$ /mobiles/page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Tried this one. Unfortunately not working for me. Maybe because site is in subfolder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems RewriteRule is not complete, move the match pattern from RewriteCond to RewriteRule, an example like this.

```
RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    show_a_product.php?product_id=$1    [NC,L]
```